# Consumer acknowledgement lost in transit

Tags: perl, rabbitmq

My test case.

I have a consumer, with `no_ack =>0`, `prefetch_count` is default. The consumer receives messages, even if previous messages are not acknowledged.

If the message is never acknowledged or `ack` message is lost in transit and if consumer never goes down, this message is never acknowledged or never sent to any other consumer. It's in the queue forever.

I don't want to timeout the message. Instead I want the message to resend after a specified timeout may be to the same consumer.

Is there a way to do this?

Thanks

Comment: Which implementation are you using?

Comment: I am using Net::RabbitMQ

Comment: Can you update your code snippet? You may also want to Try Net::Stomp like `use Net::STOMP::Client;
$stomp = Net::STOMP::Client->new(host=>'localhost', port=>61223);
$stomp->connect(login=>"guest", passcode=>"guest", host=>"rabbitmq");`  You can use the `$stomp->frame()` method to build your message.